# Date Time Functions in Algolia

Tags: algolia

I have an object in Algolia like -

```
{
   …
   “startDate”: “2013-09-26T00:00:00.000+05:30”,
   “endDate”: “2017-10-25T10:08:44.000+05:30”,
   …
}
```

Now, while retrieving the object i want to add another field as -
“endingIn”: “Ending in 9 days”

“endingIn” is days remaining from todays date till endDate. Example:

```
val daysLeft = Days.daysBetween(DateTime.now,DateTime.parse(endDate)).getDays <br>
val endingIn = s"Ending In $daysLeft days"
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also asked on https://discourse.algolia.com/t/date-time-functions/2422/ .

Answer (score 0):

you can use transformData.
from the doc :Method used to change the object passed to the item template